# como saber la posisión de un arreglo en php si ya se comparó que es el que se ha elegido?

Tags: php, mysql

ok amigos explico, estoy haciendo un carrito de compras y cuando se da el momento en que se vuelve a elegir un producto (osea el mismo una o mas veces) no se como agregar el valor de la nueva cantidad que se eligió para sumarla al arreglo.
dejo mi codigo...

```
       if (isset($_SESSION['producto'])) {
    // aqui vamos a editar si el producto existe y hay que agregarle uuna nueva cantidad

    $item_array_id_cart = array_column($_SESSION['producto'], 'item_id');
    if (!in_array($idProducto, $item_array_id_cart))
        /***** si el producto es diferente ******/ {
        $count = count($_SESSION['producto']);
        $item_array = array(
            'item_id' => $idProducto,
            'item_cantidad' => $cantidad,
            'item_nombre' => $rows['producto'],
            'item_precio' => $rows['precio_venta'],
            'item_fotografia' => $rows['foto'],
        );

        $_SESSION['producto'][$count] = $item_array;
    } else {
        /*** SI EL PRODUCTO YA HA SIDO ELEGINO ANTERIORMENTE PERO HAY QUE AGREGARLE CANTIDAD****/
        if ($resu = in_array($idProducto, $item_array_id_cart)){

                 $_SESSION['producto']['item_cantidad'] = $cantidad;
```

/**AQUI ES EL PROBLEMA, como hacer para que se agrege al elemnto del arreglo, se que hace falta la posicion, 
    al momento de comprobar si es ese el producto,
     pero no se si existe una funcion para saber la posisicon del arreglo a la cual tendria que sumarle la nueva cantidad*/

```
            echo "producto seleccionado anteriormente";
        }else{
            echo "no";
        }
    }

} else {
    /*** agregando el primer producto del arreglo ***/
    $item_array = array(
        'item_id' => $idProducto,
        'item_cantidad' => $cantidad,
        'item_nombre' => $rows['producto'],
        'item_precio' => $rows['precio_venta'],
        'item_fotografia' => $rows['foto'],
    );
    $_SESSION['producto'][0] = $item_array;
}
```

cualquier aporte es de mucha ayuda, gracias amigos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si entiendo. Digamos que ahora tienes tu carrito:

```
[ 
  [ 
    item_id =>  1,
    item_cantidad =>  2,
    item_nombre => 'Pollo'
  ],
  [ 
    item_id =>  2,
    item_cantidad =>  1,
    item_nombre =>  'Pan'
  ]
]
```

Y ese es un array llamado `$carrito` que en este caso vive en la sesión pero para lo que importa podía vivir en el caché de APC, en una BBDD o en una cookie.

Luego alguien compra tres panes, por lo que recibes un request donde el nuevo pedido es:

```
  $nuevo_pedido = [ 
    item_id =>  2,
    item_cantidad =>  3,
    item_nombre =>  'Pan'
  ]
```

Y entonces tú querrías sumar con lo anterior y dejar un carrito con cuatro panes.

**Solución**

Aunque en un array numérico el orden es fijo y sus llaves son sus respectivas posiciones, al trabajar con datos de la BBDD los arrays son contraintuitivos: empiezan desde el índice 0, mientras que el ID de una base de datos empieza desde el 1. Por lo mismo, y porque tus id no tienen por qué ser numéricos (ver nota al final)  , yo usaría en cambio el ID como llave

Tu carro inicial queda:

```
$carrito = [ 
  '1' =>  [ 
    item_id =>  1,
    item_cantidad =>  2,
    item_nombre => 'Pollo'
   ],
   '2' => [ 
    item_id =>  2,
    item_cantidad =>  1,
    item_nombre =>  'Pan'
  ]
]
```

Cuando recibes la petición de un nuevo producto añadido al carrito:

```
  $nuevo_pedido = [ 
    item_id =>  2,
    item_cantidad =>  3,
    item_nombre =>  'Pan'
  ];

  // tomo el id nuevo
  $item_id = $nuevo_pedido['item_id'];
```

Entonces revisas si ese id de producto ya está en el carrito:

```
if (array_key_exists($item_id, $carrito)) {

}
```

O bien

```
if ( isset($carrito[ $item_id ]) ) {

}
```

Si no está en el carrito, entonces lo añades:

```
$carrito[$item_id] = $nuevo_pedido;
```

Si ya está en el carrito, actualizas la cantidad:

```
$carrito[$item_id]['cantidad'] += $nuevo_pedido['cantidad'];
```

Y finalmente persistes tu carrito de vuelta en la sesión.

```
$_SESSION['producto'] = $carrito;
```

---

**NOTA:**

Si por algún motivo misterioso necesariamente tienes que guardar en la sesión los productos como un array no asociativo, entonces al persistir el carrito usarías:

```
$_SESSION['producto'] = array_values($carrito);
```

Y además, al leerlo tendrías que hacer:

```
$carrito=[];
foreach($_SESSION['producto'] as $producto) {
   $carrito[$producto['item_id']]=$producto;
}
```

---

**Pro Tip:**

Si te fijas, no tuve que procesar el carrito para obtener sus ids, porque este carrito ya tiene ids como llaves. A su vez, usando `array_key_exists` le estoy ahorrando mucho trabajo a PHP. ¿Por qué?

Bueno, ocurre que por debajo PHP usa un hashmap para clasificar las llaves que es casi inmediato de recorrer. (dado que son llaves alfanuméricas su hasheo es trivial)

Al usar `in_array` PHP hace un escaneo secuencial, porque mientras las llaves son alfanuméricas, los valores pueden ser literalmente cualquier cosa: texto, números, objetos, otros arrays, instancias de una clase, un resource de `file_open`, pulpos pegajosos, la espada de He-Man y cosas peores.

---

**Ids no numéricos?**

Los que tenemos en la ROM el concepto de la llave primaria autoincremental tendemos a pensar que si ese valor no fuera numérico se caerían los pilares de la civilización occidental.

No es así. MongoDB asigna un hash alfanumérico (ObjectId) a su llave interna. PostgreSQL ya incorporó nativamente el uso de uuid autogenerados en vez de secuencias.

Hay que perderle el miedo a usar texto como llave primaria cuando ésto tenga sentido:

- En un marketplate o eccommerce, el ID de un producto puede ser su SKU (e.g. PAN0001, NESTLE002) sólo tienes que fijar una convención para que no sean puros garabatos al azar. Marca-Correlativo es una convención aceptable
- Para un sistema de monitoreo IoT, la llave primaria pueden ser los MAC address
- Para un listado de usuarios, perfectamente el teléfono o el correo pueden ser la llave primaria, si estás diseñando el sistema desde cero.

En fin, sólo quería comentar que los autoincrementales están sobrevalorados y como en todos los lenguajes de programación (Salvo en C++ ?) los arrays empiezan desde 0, es contraintuitivo que en una tabla el registro en la posición 0 tenga ID 1.

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucha ayuda ya que llevaba un par de dias trabajando en eso, y soy un poco nuevo en el area de progra mas con los arreglos y esa explicación brindada, me haservido de mucho para mi crecimiento.